# Setting flexbox items with same width and height based on the tallest child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Yes, I know there are a lot of questions and answers regarding flexbox on this website, but nothing actually worked for me. 
So what I'm trying to do is to make three card with slightly different content, which have to be same width and height sizes. Over that I want height to be set based on the tallest child.

I tried a lot of option, and first one was:

```
flex: 1 1 0;
```

which gave me that result (red is a flex-container border):
[image]
None of them are equal.

The only solution I found is to set max-width and height. I worked, but I don't think this is the best solution. Since I use flexbox I want it to be fluid and responsive.

CSS:

```
.flex-container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.flex-items {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 0px;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    /* flex-basis: 100%; */
    /* height: 100%; */
    /* max-width: 280px; */
    /* width: max-content; */
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div *ngFor="let module of modules" class="{{module.name}}">
    <mat-card matRipple [matRippleColor]="white"  class="flex-items"
    *ngxPermissionsOnly="module.permissionsRequired">
      <div class="card-bg-image"></div>
        <span routerLink={{module.routing}}>
            <mat-card-title>
              <h1>
                  {{module.name}}
              </h1>
            </mat-card-title>
          <mat-icon>{{module.icon}}</mat-icon>
          <hr>
          <mat-card-content>
            <h3>
                {{module.description}}
            </h3>
          </mat-card-content>
        </span>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?:)

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution for your actual html structure:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 400px; /* just for example */
}

.item {
  display: flex; /* set height 100% for children */
  flex: 1 1 100%;  
  margin: 10px;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card">short text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card">Setting flexbox items with same width and height based on the tallest child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I would recomend you to set `ngFor` directive to `mat-card` to reduce number of nested elemets. And code would look like:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 400px; // just for example
}

.card {
  flex: 1 1 100%;  
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">short text</div>
  <div class="card">text</div>
  <div class="card">Setting flexbox items with same width and height based on the tallest child</div>
</div>
```